# Sum of values grouped by date to get average balance

Tags: sql

I would take balance on every consecutive day, sum it all and divide by number of days to get average account balance. To do this I prepared a query which looks something like this:

```
SELECT  AB1.DateColumn As Date, SUM(AB1.Credit - AB1.Debit) As Saldo
FROM    AccountBalance AB1
JOIN    AccountBalance AB2 ON AB1.DateColumn <= AB2.DateColumn
GROUP   BY AB1.DateColumn   -- DateColum example is like 2022-01-01
```

The main problem is when I join tables like this, using <= then I assume that SQL engine is doing calculation for each row instead of considering the sum of all rows before and just adding up to that value (Saldo). Its obvious that for big tables this is not efficient, and could take a lot of time, because I don't know the better way to skip all days without balance change, and just rewrite previous row Saldo to add to it.

What is the best way to calculate Saldo?

Comment: I've removed the majority of tags here as they conflicted, or weren't relevant. Please retag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your query.